# Array change value by index duplicate issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update the value of my array of an object matching "key". The find index is working but it's actually pushing the value instead of replacing it?

```
this.state.data = thedata Array [
  Object {
    "key": "-Lu2u6ib92Ay8Pw1O-3m",
    "question": "1",
  },
  Object {

    "key": "-Lu2u8kZRs2E4X4TgxZd",
    "question": "4",
  },
  Object {

    "key": "-Lu2u7z4--ImiPSkWa1B",
    "question": "3",
  },
this.state.data[this.state.data.findIndex(el => el.key === '-Lu2u7z4--ImiPSkWa1B')] = 'totototot';
```

Actual output pushes the value to the index but not replacing it:

```
this.state.data = thedata Array [
  totototot,
  Object {
    "key": "-Lu2u6ib92Ay8Pw1O-3m",
    "question": "1",
  },
  Object {
    "key": "-Lu2u8kZRs2E4X4TgxZd",
    "question": "4",
  },
  Object {
    "key": "-Lu2u7z4--ImiPSkWa1B",
    "question": "3",
  },
```

Expected output:

```
this.state.data = thedata Array [
  Object {
    "key": "-Lu2u6ib92Ay8Pw1O-3m",
    "question": "1",
  },
  Object {
    "key": "-Lu2u8kZRs2E4X4TgxZd",
    "question": "4",
  },
  totototot,
```

Comment: That is not valid JSON/JavaScript. Do not use an array of objects, just use a simple key-value map instead.

Comment: maybe you can add an example ? ...

Comment: Do any of these answers provide you with a resolution?  If so please accept that answer otherwise provide clear, concise notes as to why not.

Comment: Your question and your expected output do not match and all your code including the expected results are malformed JavaScript objects.  Please clean up the question with functioning code and clarity of your intent.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `question` value for the key `'-Lu2u7z4--ImiPSkWa1B'` by:

1. Finding the index
2. Looking it up in the array
3. Accessing the desired key of the field to replace OR the entire thing
4. Replacing its value

```js
let data = [{
  "key": "-Lu2u6ib92Ay8Pw1O-3m",
  "question": "1"
}, {
  "key": "-Lu2u8kZRs2E4X4TgxZd",
  "question": "4"
}, {
  "key": "-Lu2u7z4--ImiPSkWa1B",
  "question": "3"
}];
console.log("Before:",data);
// Where `data` is `this.state.data`
replaceValue(data, 'key', '-Lu2u7z4--ImiPSkWa1B', 'question', 'totototot');
console.log("After:",data);

replaceEntry(data, 'key', '-Lu2u7z4--ImiPSkWa1B',
  // Whatever you want here... (just looks the same)
  {  
    key : '-Lu2u7z4--ImiPSkWa1B',
    question : 'totototot'
  }
);


function replaceValue(data, sourceKey, sourceValue, targetKey, targetValue) {
  data[data.findIndex(el => el[sourceKey] === sourceValue)][targetKey] = targetValue;
}

function replaceEntry(data, sourceKey, sourceValue, targetValue) {
  data[data.findIndex(el => el[sourceKey] === sourceValue)] = targetValue;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: and if i want to change the entir object and not just a target value ?

Comment: @manyouuwx I will update. The `replaceEntry()` function above is effectively the same as your original code.

Comment: i have the same issue. it's not replacing but pushing instead ..

Comment: It cannot be pushing, the example above works as intended. It can't possibly be pushing because I did not call `Array.prototype.push`.

Comment: actually i found the problem can you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58937644/snapshot-key-not-working-with-value-findindex/58938301?noredirect=1#comment104135835_58938301

Comment: drive me crazy the findindex not working with snapshot.key of object but work directly when i write it manually but it return me the same value than i write !

Answer (score 0):

## The understandable way

```js
const data = [{
  "key": "-Lu2u6ib92Ay8Pw1O-3m",
  "question": "1"
}, {
  "key": "-Lu2u8kZRs2E4X4TgxZd",
  "question": "4"
}, {
  "key": "-Lu2u7z4--ImiPSkWa1B",
  "question": "3"
}];

function replaceItemHavingKeyAByB(array, a, b) {
  return array.map(element => {
    if (element.key === a) {
      return b;
    } else {
      return element;
    }
  });
}

console.log(
  replaceItemHavingKeyAByB(data, "-Lu2u7z4--ImiPSkWa1B", "totototototo")
);
```

## The short way

```js
const data = [{
  "key": "-Lu2u6ib92Ay8Pw1O-3m",
  "question": "1"
}, {
  "key": "-Lu2u8kZRs2E4X4TgxZd",
  "question": "4"
}, {
  "key": "-Lu2u7z4--ImiPSkWa1B",
  "question": "3"
}];

const replaceItemHavingKeyAByB = (array, a, b) => array.map(elt => elt.key === a ? b : elt);    

console.log(
  replaceItemHavingKeyAByB(data, "-Lu2u7z4--ImiPSkWa1B", "totototototo")
);
```

Comment: this does not appear to resolve the issue but replaces the object with a string

Comment: If you see his expected output, that is what he wants @MarkSchultheiss

Comment: Ah yes, his malformed array does have that, sorry I misread what was SAID and what is in the example.  I am going to vote the question as unclear what is being asked.

Comment: No problem :) @MarkSchultheiss